# I cannot lean left with the tkinter grid system

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a menu with a grid. I am doing this menu with the grid and buttons.

How can I lean left?

```
menubuton1 = Button(text="Genel Görünüm", fg="white", bg="#282528")
menubuton2 = Button(text="Sınıf Yönetimi", fg="white", bg="#282528")
menubuton3 = Button(text="Öğrenci Yönetimi", fg="white", bg="#282528")
menubuton4 = Button(text="İletişim", fg="white", bg="#282528")

menubuton1.grid(row=1, column=1)
menubuton2.grid(row=2, column=1)
menubuton3.grid(row=3, column=1)
menubuton4.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

[image]

Comment: `menubuton1.grid(row=1, column=1,sticky='w')` or `menubuton1.grid(row=1, column=1,sticky='ew')`

Comment: Just to expand on what `Atlas435` said: when calling `.grid` on a widget you can pass in a `sticky` parameter. The `"w"` stands for west. If you use `sticky="ew"` it will expand to fill its parent horizontally.